# Java Policy file - Deny permissions to a codebase

Tags: java, securitymanager, policyfiles

In the Java policy file, the `grant codeBase` syntax specifies which codebase should be granted which permissions. for example,

> grant codeBase "file:/C:/abc.jar" {
>   permission
>   java.security.AllPermission; };

grants `AllPermission` to code inside abc.jar

In a similar way, Is there a way to `deny` permissions to a specific syntax? Like this:

> deny codeBase "file:/C:/def.jar" {
>   permission
>   java.io.FilePermission; };

so that the code inside `def.jar` gets every other permissions except the FilePermission?

Is this even possible?

*I know this can be easily done using the `SecurityManager` class, but I just want to know if this is possible by using the policy file only.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. There is nothing like this implemented for policy files. You could write your own system, if you were really desperate.

Comment: Pro-grade - mentioned below in @kwart's answer promises that feature - as also the way to reduce performance overhead for checking all the grants. https://stackoverflow.com/a/21416571/999165

Answer (score 17):

I realize this is almost a year late but I think I am trying to do something similar.

There is a way to set the runtime permissions such that Java won't grant the global permissions.  Then you can specify only the permissions you want granted for your app.  The key is to run your app with the options below.

```
java -Djava.security.manager -Djava.security.policy==policyFile.txt MyClass
```

Note the double equals `-Djava.security.policy==policyFile.txt`.  The double equals `==` means to use *only* the permissions in the named file as opposed to the single equal sign `-Djava.security.policy=policyFile.txt` which means use these permissions in addition to the inherited global permissions.

Then create a policy file excluding the permissions you want to deny:

```
// policyFile.txt
grant codeBase "file:/C:/abc.jar" {

    // list of permissions minus the ones you want to deny
    // for example, the following would give the application
    // ONLY AudioPermission and AWTPermission.  Other
    // permissions such as java.io.FilePermission would be
    // denied.

    permission javax.sound.sampled.AudioPermission;
    permission java.awt.AWTPermission;

}
```

Comment: And I realize that this is another 2 years later... The point of having 'deny' is that it is impossible to know the full list of 'allows' for an unknown, say hosted app on a server, application. Say for instance, you want to disallow writing to "java.*" system properties, but all other can be used by the app. It is for this reason a 'deny codeBase' would be good. And that is what I intend to do...

Comment: I'm trying to deny the user from reading any files except my home directory by having the `permission java.io.FilePermission "/home/temp/*", "";` inside the `grant {` block. I've used the `==` to specify the policy file, yet it allows me to read files from other directories and even execute commands like `chmod` as the current user. is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 9):

You can use [Prograde](https://github.com/olukas/pro-grade) library, which implements policy file with deny rules.

Add following Maven dependency to your app

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sourceforge.pro-grade</groupId>
    <artifactId>pro-grade</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

And then enable it for your application by using standard system properties:

```
-Djava.security.manager=net.sourceforge.prograde.sm.ProgradeSecurityManager -Djava.security.policy==/path/to/your/application.policy
```

or you can just replace programatically the Policy implementation in your code:

```
System.setProperty("java.security.policy","/path/to/your/application.policy");
Policy.setPolicy(new ProgradePolicyFile());
```

The syntax of policy file stays similar to the standard implementation, but you can use `deny` instead of `grant` and you can also change priorities by using keyword `priority` (default value is `"deny"` - to stay backward compatible).

For instance, you can do sth. like:

```
grant {
    permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "*";
};

deny {
    permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "exitVM.*";
};
```

Other examples are [here](https://github.com/olukas/progradeTests/blob/master/src/test/resources/policyfiles/).

Comment: Even though directly calling `System.exit(0);` fails, I bet you can use the other `RuntimePermissions` to get the equivalent of `exitVM.*`.

Answer (score 0):

One of the least involved approaches towards attaining *deny rule* support, is to:

- Define a "negative" `Permission` subclass that wraps a regular positive permission and negates it; and
- wrap the default `Policy` such that it (its wrapper) understands such permissions.

**The `DeniedPermission` class**

```
package com.example.q5003565;

import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Modifier;
import java.security.BasicPermission;
import java.security.Permission;
import java.security.UnresolvedPermission;
import java.text.MessageFormat;

/**
 * A representation of a "negative" privilege.
 * <p>
 * A <code>DeniedPermission</code>, when "granted" to some <code>ProtectionDomain</code>, represents
 * a privilege which <em>cannot</em> be exercised, regardless of any positive permissions
 * (<code>AllPermission</code> included) possessed. In other words, if a set of granted permissions,
 * <em>P</em>, contains a permission of this class, <em>D</em>, then the set of effectively granted
 * permissions is<br/>
 * <br/>
 * &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<em>{ P<sub>implied</sub> - D<sub>implied</sub> }</em>.
 * </p>
 * <p>
 * Each instance of this class encapsulates a <em>target permission</em>, representing the
 * "positive" permission being negated.
 * </p>
 * Denied permissions employ the following naming scheme:<br/>
 * <br/>
 * &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<em>&lt;target_class_name&gt;:&lt;target_name&gt;(:&lt;target_actions&gt;)</em><br/>
 * <br/>
 * where:
 * <ul>
 * <li><em>&lt;target_class_name&gt;</em> is the fully qualified name of the target permission's
 * class,</li>
 * <li><em>&lt;target_name&gt;</em> is the {@linkplain #getName() name} of the target
 * permission,</li>
 * <li><em>(&lt;target_actions&gt;)</em> is, optionally, the {@linkplain #getActions() actions
 * string} of the target permission, and</li>
 * <li>the <em>':'</em> character stands for itself.</li>
 * </ul>
 * A denied permission, having a target permission <em>t</em>, is said to
 * {@linkplain #implies(Permission) <em>imply</em>} another permission <em>p</em>, iff:
 * <ul>
 * <li>p <em>is not</em> itself a denied permission, and <code>(t.implies(p) == true)</code>,
 * or</li>
 * <li>p <em>is</em> a denied permission, with a target <em>t1</em>, and
 * <code>(t.implies(t1) == true)</code>.</li>
 * </ul>
 * <p>
 * It is the responsibility of the policy decision point (e.g., the <code>Policy</code> provider) to
 * take denied permission semantics into account when issuing authorization statements.
 * </p>
 */
public final class DeniedPermission extends BasicPermission {

    private static final String NULL_STR_ARG = "<null>", EMPTY_STR_ARG = "<empty> ";
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2102974454790623344L;

    private final Permission target;

    /**
     * Instantiates a <code>DeniedPermission</code> that encapsulates a target permission of the
     * indicated class, specified name and, optionally, actions.
     * 
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException
     *             if:
     *             <ul>
     *             <li><code>targetClassName</code> is <code>null</code>, the empty string, does not
     *             refer to a concrete <code>Permission</code> descendant, or refers to
     *             <code>DeniedPermission.class</code> or <code>UnresolvedPermission.class</code>.</li>
     *             <li><code>targetName</code> is <code>null</code>.</li>
     *             <li><code>targetClassName</code> cannot be instantiated, and it's the caller's fault;
     *             e.g., because <code>targetName</code> and/or <code>targetActions</code> do not adhere
     *             to the naming constraints of the target class; or due to the target class not
     *             exposing a <code>(String name)</code>, or <code>(String name, String actions)</code>
     *             constructor, depending on whether <code>targetActions</code> is <code>null</code> or
     *             not.</li>
     *             </ul>
     * @throws SecurityException
     *             if a <code>SecurityManager</code>, <code>sm</code>, is installed, and the invocation
     *             <code>sm.checkPackageAccess(targetClassPackageName)</code> (where
     *             <code>targetClassPackageName</code> is the package of the class referred to
     *             by <code>targetClassName</code>) denies access.
     */
    public static DeniedPermission newDeniedPermission(String targetClassName, String targetName,
            String targetActions) {
        if (targetClassName == null || targetClassName.trim().isEmpty() || targetName == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("[targetClassName] and [targetName] must not be null or empty.");
        }
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(targetClassName).append(":").append(targetName);
        if (targetName != null) {
            sb.append(":").append(targetName);
        }
        return new DeniedPermission(sb.toString());
    }

    /**
     * Instantiates a <code>DeniedPermission</code> that encapsulates the given target permission.
     * 
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException
     *             if <code>target</code> is <code>null</code>, a <code>DeniedPermission</code>, or an
     *             <code>UnresolvedPermission</code>.
     */
    public static DeniedPermission newDeniedPermission(Permission target) {
        if (target == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("[target] must not be null.");
        }
        if (target instanceof DeniedPermission || target instanceof UnresolvedPermission) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("[target] must not be a DeniedPermission or an UnresolvedPermission.");
        }
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(target.getClass().getName()).append(":").append(target.getName());
        String targetActions = target.getActions();
        if (targetActions != null) {
            sb.append(":").append(targetActions);
        }
        return new DeniedPermission(sb.toString(), target);
    }

    private static Permission constructTargetPermission(String targetClassName, String targetName,
            String targetActions) {
        Class<?> targetClass;
        try {
            targetClass = Class.forName(targetClassName);
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
            if (targetClassName.trim().isEmpty()) {
                targetClassName = EMPTY_STR_ARG;
            }
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    MessageFormat.format("Target Permission class [{0}] not found.", targetClassName));
        }
        if (!Permission.class.isAssignableFrom(targetClass) || Modifier.isAbstract(targetClass.getModifiers())) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(MessageFormat
                    .format("Target Permission class [{0}] is not a (concrete) Permission.", targetClassName));
        }
        if (targetClass == DeniedPermission.class || targetClass == UnresolvedPermission.class) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "Target Permission class must not be a DeniedPermission itself, nor an UnresolvedPermission.");
        }
        Constructor<?> targetCtor;
        try {
            if (targetActions == null) {
                targetCtor = targetClass.getConstructor(String.class);
            }
            else {
                targetCtor = targetClass.getConstructor(String.class, String.class);
            }
        }
        catch (NoSuchMethodException nsme) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(MessageFormat.format(
                    "Target Permission class [{0}]  (String name) or (String name, String actions) constructor.",
                    targetClassName));
        }
        try {
            return (Permission) targetCtor
                    .newInstance(((targetCtor.getParameterCount() == 1) ? new Object[] { targetName }
                            : new Object[] { targetName, targetActions }));
        }
        catch (ReflectiveOperationException roe) {
            if (roe instanceof InvocationTargetException) {
                if (targetName == null) {
                    targetName = NULL_STR_ARG;
                }
                else if (targetName.trim().isEmpty()) {
                    targetName = EMPTY_STR_ARG;
                }
                if (targetActions == null) {
                    targetActions = NULL_STR_ARG;
                }
                else if (targetActions.trim().isEmpty()) {
                    targetActions = EMPTY_STR_ARG;
                }
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(MessageFormat.format(
                        "Could not instantiate target Permission class [{0}]; provided target name [{1}] and/or target [{2}] actions potentially erroneous.",
                        targetClassName, targetName, targetActions), roe);
            }
            throw new RuntimeException(MessageFormat.format(
                    "Could not instantiate target Permission class [{0}] - an unforeseen error occurred, see attached cause for details.",
                    targetClassName), roe);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Instantiates a <code>DeniedPermission</code> that encapsulates a target permission of the class,
     * name and, optionally, actions, collectively provided as the <code>name</code> argument.
     * 
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException
     *             if:
     *             <ul>
     *             <li><code>name</code>'s target permission class name component is empty, does not
     *             refer to a concrete <code>Permission</code> descendant, or refers to
     *             <code>DeniedPermission.class</code> or <code>UnresolvedPermission.class</code>.</li>
     *             <li><code>name</code>'s target name component is <code>empty</code></li>
     *             <li>the target permission class cannot be instantiated, and it's the caller's fault;
     *             e.g., because <code>name</code>'s target name and/or target actions component(s) do
     *             not adhere to the naming constraints of the target class; or due to the target class
     *             not exposing a <code>(String name)</code>, or
     *             <code>(String name, String actions)</code> constructor, depending on whether the
     *             target actions component is empty or not.</li>
     *             </ul>
     * @throws SecurityException
     *             if a <code>SecurityManager</code>, <code>sm</code>, is installed, and the invocation
     *             <code>sm.checkPackageAccess(targetClassPackageName)</code>
     *             (where <code>targetClassPackageName</code> is the package of the class referred to
     *             by <code>name</code>'s target name component) denies access.
     */
    public DeniedPermission(String name) {
        super(name);
        String[] comps = name.split(":");
        if (comps.length < 2) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(MessageFormat.format("Malformed [name] argument: {0}", name));
        }
        this.target = constructTargetPermission(comps[0], comps[1], ((comps.length < 3) ? null : comps[2]));
    }

    private DeniedPermission(String name, Permission target) {
        super(name);
        this.target = target;
    }

    /**
     * Checks whether the given permission is implied by this one, as per the
     * {@linkplain DeniedPermission overview}.
     */
    @Override
    public boolean implies(Permission p) {
        if (p instanceof DeniedPermission) {
            return target.implies(((DeniedPermission) p).target);
        }
        return target.implies(p);
    }

    /**
     * Returns this denied permission's target permission.
     */
    public Permission getTargetPermission() {
        return target;
    }

}
```

**The `DenyingPolicy` class**

```
package com.example.q5003565;

import java.security.AccessController;
import java.security.CodeSource;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.NoSuchProviderException;
import java.security.Permission;
import java.security.PermissionCollection;
import java.security.Policy;
import java.security.PrivilegedAction;
import java.security.ProtectionDomain;
import java.security.UnresolvedPermission;
import java.util.Enumeration;

/**
 * Wrapper that adds rudimentary {@link DeniedPermission} processing capabilities to the standard
 * file-backed <code>Policy</code>.
 */
public final class DenyingPolicy extends Policy {

    /*
     * doPrivileged needed just in case there's already a SecurityManager installed at class loading
     * time.
     */
    private static final ProtectionDomain OWN_PD = AccessController
            .doPrivileged((PrivilegedAction<ProtectionDomain>) DenyingPolicy.class::getProtectionDomain);

    private final Policy defaultPolicy;

    {
        try {
            // will fail unless the calling acc has SecurityPermission "createPolicy.javaPolicy"
            defaultPolicy = Policy.getInstance("javaPolicy", null, "SUN");
        }
        catch (NoSuchProviderException | NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Could not acquire default Policy.", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public PermissionCollection getPermissions(CodeSource codesource) {
        return defaultPolicy.getPermissions(codesource);
    }

    @Override
    public PermissionCollection getPermissions(ProtectionDomain domain) {
        return defaultPolicy.getPermissions(domain);
    }

    /**
     * @return <code>true</code> iff:
     *         <ul>
     *         <li><code>permission</code> <em>is not</em> an instance of
     *         <code>DeniedPermission</code>,</li>
     *         <li>an <code>implies(domain, permission)</code> invocation on the system-default
     *         <code>Policy</code> yields <code>true</code>, and</li>
     *         <li><code>permission</code> <em>is not</em> implied by any <code>DeniedPermission</code>s
     *         having potentially been assigned to <code>domain</code>.</li>
     *         </ul>
     */
    @Override
    public boolean implies(ProtectionDomain domain, Permission permission) {
        if (OWN_PD.equals(domain)) {
            /*
             * Recursive invocation due to a privilege-requiring method we invoked. If you're uncomfortable with
             * this, get rid of it and grant (via .policy) a RuntimePermission "accessClassInPackage.*" to
             * OWN_PD.
             */
            return true;
        }
        if (permission instanceof DeniedPermission) {
            /*
             * At the policy decision level, DeniedPermissions can only themselves imply, not be implied (as
             * they take away, rather than grant, privileges). Returning true for a deny rule would be
             * more confusing than convenient.
             */
            return false;
        }

        if (!defaultPolicy.implies(domain, permission)) {
            // permission not granted--no need to check whether denied
            return false;
        }

        /*
         * Permission granted--now check whether there's an overriding DeniedPermission. The following
         * assumes that defaultPolicy (its wrapped PolicySpi) is a sun.security.provider.PolicySpiFile
         * (other implementations might not support #getPermissions(ProtectionDomain)
         * and/or handle resolution of UnresolvedPermissions differently).
         */

        Enumeration<Permission> perms = defaultPolicy.getPermissions(domain).elements();
        while (perms.hasMoreElements()) {
            Permission p = perms.nextElement();
            /*
             * DeniedPermissions will generally remain unresolved, as no code is expected to check whether other
             * code has been "granted" such a permission.
             */
            if (p instanceof UnresolvedPermission) {
                UnresolvedPermission up = (UnresolvedPermission) p;
                if (up.getUnresolvedType().equals(DeniedPermission.class.getName())) {
                    // force resolution
                    defaultPolicy.implies(domain, up);
                    // evaluate right away, to avoid reiterating over the collection
                    p = AccessController.doPrivileged(
                            (PrivilegedAction<Permission>) () -> new DeniedPermission(up.getUnresolvedName()));
                }
            }
            if (p instanceof DeniedPermission && p.implies(permission)) {
                // permission denied
                return false;
            }
        }
        // permission granted
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void refresh() {
        defaultPolicy.refresh();
    }

}
```

**Usage**

Just embed `DeniedPermission`s within plain old *grant* rules; for instance, the following rule will grant *everything **but*** the ability to *read* System Properties with a name starting with "user.", *to some.jar*'s classes.

```
grant codeBase "file:/home/your_user/classpath/some.jar" {
    permission java.security.AllPermission;
    permission com.example.q5003565.DeniedPermission "java.util.PropertyPermission:user.*:read";
};
```

Then install a `DenyingPolicy` via `Policy.setPolicy(new DenyingPolicy());`.

**Caveat:** While semantically correct, as was mentioned in a previous answer's comment, the above example is ineffective, as it *still* grants dangerous permissions, such as `SecurityPermission "setPolicy"`, which implicitly allow sandboxed code to do whatever it pleases, including the action prohibited by the `DeniedPermission`. To prevent this from occurring, rather than subtracting permissions from `AllPermission`, consider subtracting from an `AllSafePermission` instead, where `AllSafePermission` is defined such that it `implies` everything **except** known sandbox-defeating permissions<sup>1</sup>.

**Notes**

- Any permission can be wrapped by a denied permission, as long as it follows the standard target name-action(s) convention, exposes a `(String)` and/or `(String, String)` constructor, and appropriately overrides `implies(Permission)`.
- To deny multiple permissions at once:

  - Create an ordinary permission subclass that `implies` the to-be-denied permissions.
  - "Grant" a denied permission, in turn referencing an instance of your implementation, from the policy configuration.
- The `DenyingPolicy` *does not* prevent permissions [statically](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/ProtectionDomain.html#getPermissions--) assigned to a protection domain (such as `RuntimePermission "exitVM.*"` granted by default to code originating from the classpath) from being granted, as, generally, evaluation of such permissions occurs prior to evaluation of permissions maintained by the policy. In order to deny any of these permissions as well, you will have to replace the `ClassLoader` with one that:

  - does either not grant the permissions in the first place, or
  - [maps](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#defineClass-java.lang.String-byte:A-int-int-java.security.ProtectionDomain-) classes it loads to instances of a `ProtectionDomain` subclass, that overrides `implies(Permission)` such that:

    - it always delegates to policy, or
    - processes `DeniedPermission`s in a manner similar to `DenyingPolicy`.

---

<sup>1: For a listing of such permissions see e.g. [Maass, M. (2016). A Theory and Tools for Applying Sandboxes Effectively.](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/A-Theory-and-Tools-for-Applying-Sandboxes-Effectiv-Maass/0ceed97c5761f70d8016453897e778a172691ad4), table 3.1 (page 47).</sup>