# How to allow the thread to modify itself only

Tags: java, multithreading

In the documentation of the [interrupt()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt--) method we have:

```
Throws:
    SecurityException - if the current thread cannot modify this thread
```

The [source code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/jdk8-b132/src/share/classes/java/lang/Thread.java#l910) of the method is this:

```
public void interrupt() {
     if (this != Thread.currentThread())
         checkAccess();   //checking access
     //The rest is ommited
 }
```

The `checkAccess` method, in turn is implemented as follows:

```
public final void checkAccess() {
    SecurityManager security = System.getSecurityManager();
    if (security != null) {
        security.checkAccess(this);
    }
}
```

By default, as far as I got any thread is permitted to modify anyone else thread.

But is there a way to specify `modifyThread` permission in the `java.policy` file to allow a thread modify only itself?

In the `java.policy` I could find the only `grant{ ... }` section. Is there a way to deny such threads communications?

Comment: Modify itself how? The only relevant operations are `interrupt(), setName(),` and `setPriority()`. Is it one of these you're worried about? And if so why?

Comment: @VenkataRaju He knows that, he is asking about fine-grained permissions (that don't exist).

Comment: @EJP I've already got that.

Answer (score 1):

In order for you to use [policy files](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/PolicyFiles.html) to control who can call `Thread.interrupt()` there would need to be a [policy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/permissions.html) in place which regulates this access. As you've seen there isn't a `SecurityManager.checkPermission()` call in `Thread.interrupt()`, so this is clearly not possible.  This is by design, because policies are meant to limit the access of code sources, not threads (which can be executing code from multiple source locations).  If a code source is not granted access to a certain policy, it can *never* run code protected by that policy.

Instead, `Thread` access is regulated by the [`SecurityManager.checkAccess(Thread)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/SecurityManager.html#checkAccess-java.lang.Thread-) method. From [`Thread.checkAccess()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#checkAccess--):

> Determines if the currently running thread has permission to modify this thread.
>
> If there is a security manager, its `checkAccess` method is called with this thread as its argument.

And `SecurityManager.checkAccess(Thread)` describes exactly how you can restrict access:

> Throws a `SecurityException` if the calling thread is not allowed to modify the thread argument.
>
> This method is invoked for the current security manager by the `stop`, `suspend`, `resume`, `setPriority`, `setName`, and `setDaemon` methods of class Thread. [*sic. this should include `interrupt` as well*]
>
> .... If the thread argument is not a system thread, this method just returns silently.
>
> Applications that want a stricter policy should override this method....

So there you go.  Define a custom `SecurityManager` that raises an exception in `checkAccess(Thread)` to restrict who can interrupt or otherwise modify threads..

---

To your second question about granting vs. denying permissions, the [Policy File Syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/PolicyFiles.html#FileSyntax) page details that there is only the `grant` statement, [there is no `deny` mechanism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5003565/java-policy-file-deny-permissions-to-a-codebase).